How to do nested sorting in postgresql
I have columns id (string), parentId (string or null) and order (number). It's tree like structure where rows with the same parentId are children of the same node. order is used to sort children for each parent (so they might be the same for childs of different parents).
For a given id, I want to extract its previous and next row. I need to somehow sort data first by parentId looking at its order and then isnert in the middle of table their childrens, again sorted by order and again (recursion). Here is how my data looks like after running query:
SELECT "content"."id", "content"."parentId", "content"."order" FROM "course_content_entity" "content" WHERE ( "content"."deletedAt" IS NULL ) AND ("content"."courseId" = '05dd28d5-a244-4ca1-b7fb-fc3bc7b2e422') order by "content"."parentId", "content"."order" 

enter image description here
It's of course now what I want. Any ideas how to do that?
EDIT
Just to explain why I need it: for a given child in a tree (which represent a course), I need to add a navigation to go to the next and previous article which might have different parents.
Thanks to @Islingre query, I manage to edit it to fit my database structure and I've got the following query and results:
// query
WITH RECURSIVE node(id, "parentId", "order", "name", position_array) AS (
    SELECT
        root.id,
        root."parentId",
        root.order,
        root.name,
        ARRAY[ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY root.order, root.id)] AS position_array
    FROM course_content_entity root
    WHERE root."parentId" IS NULL AND root."courseId" = '18f75c26-3608-49c2-8e1c-56618b35c780'
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        child.id,
        child."parentId",
        child.order,
        child.name,
        parent.position_array || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY child."parentId" ORDER BY child.order) AS position_array
    FROM course_content_entity child
    INNER JOIN node parent  ON parent.id::uuid = child."parentId"::uuid
    WHERE child."courseId" = '18f75c26-3608-49c2-8e1c-56618b35c780'

  --parent.id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM child."parentId" 
)
SELECT
    n.id,
    n."parentId",
    n.order,
    n.name,
    n.position_array,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n.position_array) AS dfs_position
FROM node n
-- WHERE n.id = '7fcebdc8-9dd4-43e3-afd4-641695d8f769'
ORDER BY dfs_position;


Result:
Result of a query
I added to the query twice:
root."courseId" = '18f75c26-3608-49c2-8e1c-56618b35c780' to get only contents from a given course. So it works and now I need to get row before and after a particular node. Because I'm working in typeorm,  it would be even better to have this query written using that library and its queryBuilder.
This is my Entity:
@Entity()
export class CourseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, default: null })
  slug: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  description: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.courses)
  author!: UserEntity;

  @OneToMany(() => CourseContentEntity, (content) => content.course, { cascade: ['soft-remove'] })
  content: Array<CourseContentEntity>;


  constructor(partial: Partial<CourseEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}



@Entity()
export class CourseContentEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  slug: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  parentId: string;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  order: number;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  content: string;

  constructor(partial: Partial<CourseContentEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}


And this is how I handle searching for next and previous node:

  async getPagination(contentId: string) {
    const content = await this._courseContentRepository.findOne({
      where: { id: contentId },
      relations: { course: true },
    });
    const query = this._courseContentRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('content')
      .leftJoin('content.course', 'course')
      .andWhere('course.id = :courseId', { courseId: content.course.id });

    /* NEXT */
    const getNext = async (content: CourseContentEntity) => {
      const nextQuery = query.clone();
      if (content.parentId) {
        nextQuery.where('content.parentId = :parentId', { parentId: content.parentId });
      } else {
        nextQuery.where('content.parentId IS NULL');
      }
      return await nextQuery
        .andWhere('content.order > :order', { order: content.order })
        .orderBy('content.order', 'ASC')
        .getOne();
    };

    const firstChild = await this._courseContentRepository.findOne({
      where: { parentId: content.id },
    });
    let next = firstChild;

    // Try to get next sibling
    if (!next) next = await getNext(content);
    if (!next && content.parentId) {
      // It's a last child node -> take node after parent node
      const parent = await this._courseContentRepository.findOne({
        where: { id: content.parentId },
      });

      next = await getNext(parent);
    }

    /* PREV */
    const getPrev = async (parentId: string | null, order: number) => {
      const prevQuery = query.clone();
      if (parentId) {
        prevQuery.where('content.parentId = :parentId', { parentId: parentId });
      } else {
        prevQuery.where('content.parentId IS NULL');
      }
      return await prevQuery.andWhere('content.order < :order', { order }).orderBy('content.order', 'DESC').getOne();
    };

    let prev = await getPrev(content.parentId, content.order);
    if (prev) {
      const lastChild = await query
        .andWhere('content.parentId = :parentId', { parentId: prev.id })
        .orderBy('content.order', 'DESC')
        .getOne();
      if (lastChild) prev = lastChild;
    } else {
      if (content.parentId) {
        const parent = await this._courseContentRepository.findOne({
          where: { id: content.parentId },
        });
        prev = parent;
      } else {
        prev = await getPrev(null, content.order);
        if (prev) {
          const lastChild = await query
            .andWhere('content.parentId = :parentId', { parentId: prev.id })
            .orderBy('content.order', 'DESC')
            .getOne();
          if (lastChild) prev = lastChild;
        }
      }
    }

    // const nextQuery = query
    //   .select('LEAD(content.id) over (order by content.order asc) as next_id')
    //   .addSelect('LEAD(content.name) over (order by content.order asc) as next_name')
    //   .where('content.parentId = :parentId', { parentId: content.parentId })
    //   .andWhere('content.id = :contentId', { contentId: contentId });

    return {
      next: next
        ? {
            id: next.id,
            name: next.name,
          }
        : undefined,
      prev: prev
        ? {
            id: prev.id,
            name: prev.name,
          }
        : undefined,
    };
  }


I'm wondering which soluton will be better in the end (mine current one or sorting the tree).

Do you look for a PostgreSQL answer or for a TypeORM answer? As both are tagged in this question...
By the provided SQL query, I would guess you look for a PostgreSQL answer, is this correct?
Please also include images directly - or even better: paste your example data in the question - instead of hiding them behind non-descriptive links.
Please update (aka edit) the question and include the missing information.

To get the rows sorted in the tree's DFS order, you can try the following query:
WITH RECURSIVE node(id, parent_id, position, position_array) AS (
    SELECT
        root.id,
        root.parent_id,
        root.position,
        ARRAY[ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY root.position, root.id)] AS position_array
    FROM forest_node root
    WHERE root.parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        child.id,
        child.parent_id,
        child.position,
        parent.position_array || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY child.parent_id ORDER BY child.position) AS position_array
    FROM forest_node child
    INNER JOIN node parent ON parent.id = child.parent_id
)
SELECT
    n.id,
    n.parent_id,
    n.position,
    n.position_array,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n.position_array) AS dfs_position
FROM node n
ORDER BY dfs_position;

This query starts with the roots (parent_id IS NULL) and recursively (WITH RECURSIVE) adds their children, building the position_array via the ROW_NUMBER() OVER () window function (Window Function Tutorial, List of Window Functions). The sorting is finally done via ordering by the position_array, relying on array comparison (Array Functions and Operators).
Renaming forest_node to "course_content_entity" and id, parent_id and position to "id", "parentId" and "order" should make this applicable to your case. I chose different names for multiple reasons, including a better general example and the urge to avoid quoted identifiers.
Assumptions:

A root node may or may not have the position set. Non-root nodes always have the position set.
There might be multiple root nodes in the table (this is why I used forest_node instead of tree_node as tablename). We order them by their position and break ties by the id. All nodes of the same tree appear next to each other in the final list.

Note: if there should be some cycle in the table, the query will ignore all entries of this cycle, as there is no path ending in a root node.
Final remark: if you are working on a big table, it might be much more efficient to write a function that just traverses the tree node-by-node to find the "DFS-neighbors". The provided query will always work with all rows of the table which might become a bottleneck.
Used for testing purposes:
CREATE TABLE forest_node (
    id text NOT NULL,
    parent_id text,
    position integer CHECK(position IS NOT NULL OR parent_id IS NULL),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE(parent_id, position)
);

INSERT INTO forest_node (id, parent_id, position)
VALUES
    ('root1', NULL, NULL),
    ('root2', NULL, NULL),
    ('root3', NULL, NULL),
    ('root1.1', 'root1', 1),
    ('root1.2', 'root1', 2),
    ('root3.2', 'root3', 2),
    ('root3.1', 'root3', 1),
    ('root2.1', 'root2', 1),
    ('root2.2', 'root2', 2),
    ('root2.1.1', 'root2.1', 1),
    ('root2.1.2', 'root2.1', 2),
    ('root2.4', 'root2', 4),
    ('root2.3', 'root2', 3);


Awesome! I'm looking rather for typeorm answer but I could run as well this raw query. However, I encountered problem with     INNER JOIN node parent ON parent.id = child.parent_id where error is: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.  My id is of type UUID where parentId might be null. How to fix that?

Do I understand correctly, that the id column is of type uuid while the parentId is of type text (or varchar or something similar)? It would be best if they had the same data type (best both uuid) and if a foreign key constraint would be established (@ManyToOne in TypeORM). To adjust the query above, just add a cast of the id: INNER JOIN node parent ON parent.id::text = child.parent_id. For big tables, this might have again notable impact, but I hope it works for you.

Regarding a TypeORM answer.. not sure about it. Would at least need to see how the entity is defined. If you want me to check it and possibly give it a try, please edit the question and append the entity definition.

Sorry for late reply - I edited my question and added much more context and information. I really appreciate your help!

For a TypeORM approach to this problem, I see following possibilities:

hard-code a prepared statement (parameterized SQL query)
traverse the tree by fetching nodes one-by-one
use QueryBuilder.addCommonTableExpression() and get it to work with WITH RECURSIVE (not sure if it is able to.. possibly not, at least not via QueryBuilder but only hard-coded SQL, I belief)

I would suggest traversing the tree and will provide some generalized code for this in the following.
Entity:
import {
    Check,
    Column,
    Entity,
    Index,
    JoinColumn,
    ManyToOne,
    OneToMany,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
@Check("parent_id IS NULL OR position IS NOT NULL")
@Index(["parent", "position"], { unique: true })
@Index(["name"], { unique: true })
export class ForestNode {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id?: string; // ? because id will only get assigned on save, not already in constructor

    @Column()
    name: string; // added property to easily identify nodes

    @ManyToOne(() => ForestNode, (parent) => parent.children, { nullable: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    parent?: ForestNode | null; // ? because relation might not be loaded when record is fetched from DB

    @Column({ nullable: true, type: "int" })
    position: number | null;

    constructor(
        name: string,
        parent: ForestNode | null,
        position: number | null,
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.position = position;
    }

    @OneToMany(() => ForestNode, (child) => child.parent)
    children?: ForestNode[]; // ? because relation might not be loaded when record is fetched from DB - and no value assigned in constructor
}

Results in a DB table like this (using the SnakeNamingStrategy from typeorm-naming-strategies):
                        Table "public.forest_node"
  Column   |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |      Default
-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------
 id        | uuid              |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
 name      | character varying |           | not null |
 position  | integer           |           |          |
 parent_id | uuid              |           |          |
Indexes:
    "PK_3249a860f2197601caa2e20f3a9" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "IDX_b809a8da806808ab77c47a0e95" UNIQUE, btree (name)
    "IDX_c6597116d3f149e5889c912e8d" UNIQUE, btree (parent_id, "position")
Check constraints:
    "CHK_e53d2fb9afed95a164b1b04a3b" CHECK (parent_id IS NULL OR "position" IS NOT NULL)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "FK_db6b2f9beaeb26ff7a41a16f220" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES forest_node(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "forest_node" CONSTRAINT "FK_db6b2f9beaeb26ff7a41a16f220" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES forest_node(id)

Example on how to traverse the tree to find the DFS predecessor:
async function getDfsPredecessorNode(
    forestNodeRepo: Repository<ForestNode>,
    node: ForestNode,
) {
    const { parent, position } = node;

    if (parent === undefined) {
        throw new Error("parent relation not loaded");
    }
    if (parent === null) {
        return null; // root has no predecessor
    }

    if (position === null) {
        throw new Error("non-root cannot have null position");
    }

    const predecessorSibling = await forestNodeRepo.findOne({
        where: {
            parent,
            position: LessThan(position),
        },
        order: { position: "DESC" },
        relations: { parent: true },
    });

    if (!predecessorSibling) {
        return parent;
    }

    // we want now to find the last node in the subtree rooted in predecessorSibling
    let subtreeRoot = predecessorSibling;

    while (true) {
        const lastChild = await forestNodeRepo.findOne({
            where: {
                parent: subtreeRoot,
            },
            order: { position: "DESC" },
        });

        if (!lastChild) {
            return subtreeRoot;
        }

        subtreeRoot = lastChild;
    }
}

To find the DFS successor, you can implement a similar approach (if node has children, return first child; otherwise, start at the current node and check if it has a successor sibling, if so, return it, else repeat this step with the parent as the current node - if there is no parent anymore, return null).
